# How can I make two figures same size in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, eps

I am trying to make the figures same size. In the figure 1, they seem like they are in same dimensions, however when I include them in the latex they are no more aligned which can be seen in figure 2. If I make the sizes of figures equal, one of the picture is going to skew which can be seen in figure 3. What could be my strategy to make them aligned without skewing problems? [image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code how you include them in latex?

Comment: Based on the images alone, I'd say you want to look into the `adjutsbox` package and it's `valign` key for images, or into `\raisebox`. For the 3rd image: Never specify both the width and height of an image at the same time (and if you must specify both, always include the `keepaspectratio` key)